# Qt 4.8.4 giving error in debug mode compilation

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I have installed Qt 4.8.4 for Visual Studio 2010.
qt-win-opensource-4.8.4-vs2010.exe
http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.4/

Qt project file:

```
LIBS += -lqaxserver \  
        -lqaxcontainer
```

In my Qt GUI application I am using QAxobject to access ms-excel.

When I compile my project in release mode, I do not get any error. And GUI is running as expected. I am able to generate excel files using QAxObject objects.

But I am getting the following 3 errors when doing a debug build:

```
file not found: qaxcontainer.lib(qaxbase.obj)
file not found: qaxcontainer.lib(qaxobject.obj)
file not found: qaxcontainer.lib(qaxtypes.obj)
```

Why does this happen only in debug builds? How do I solve it?

Edit :----

I commented LIBS & added CONFIG. Still no change release mode is compiling debug is giving error.

```
#LIBS += -lqaxserver \
#        -lqaxcontainer
CONFIG += qaxserver
CONFIG += qaxcontainer
```

Now i am getting seven errors :----

```
AxServerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj) : error LNK2005: "class QColor __cdecl OLEColorToQColor(unsigned int)" (?OLEColorToQColor@@YA?AVQColor@@I@Z) already defined in QAxContainerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj)
QAxServerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj) : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl QVariantToVARIANT(class QVariant const &,struct tagVARIANT &,class QByteArray const &,bool)" (?QVariantToVARIANT@@YA_NABVQVariant@@AAUtagVARIANT@@ABVQByteArray@@_N@Z) already defined in QAxContainerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj)
QAxServerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj) : error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl QVariantToVoidStar(class QVariant const &,void *,class QByteArray const &,unsigned int)" (?QVariantToVoidStar@@YA_NABVQVariant@@PAXABVQByteArray@@I@Z) already defined in QAxContainerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj)
QAxServerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj) : error LNK2005: "class QVariant __cdecl VARIANTToQVariant(struct tagVARIANT const &,class QByteArray const &,unsigned int)" (?VARIANTToQVariant@@YA?AVQVariant@@ABUtagVARIANT@@ABVQByteArray@@I@Z) already defined in QAxContainerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj)
QAxServerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl clearVARIANT(struct tagVARIANT *)" (?clearVARIANT@@YAXPAUtagVARIANT@@@Z) already defined in QAxContainerd.lib(qaxtypes.obj)
QAxServerd.lib(qaxserver.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class QAxFactory * __cdecl qax_instantiate(void)" (?qax_instantiate@@YAPAVQAxFactory@@XZ) referenced in function "class QAxFactory * __cdecl qAxFactory(void)" (?qAxFactory@@YAPAVQAxFactory@@XZ)
debug\geny.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.4\lib" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"debug\geny.intermediate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /OUT:debug\geny.exe @C:\Users\dguleria\AppData\Local\Temp\geny.exe.17776.15.jom
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the libraries are named differently in the debug version. You shouldn't use `LIBS` for Qt libraries. You should be telling qmake to figure out the link options by doing:

```
CONFIG += qaxcontainer
```

This is documented here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/activeqt-container.html

Comment: still not working for debug mode.. I have edited the original post .. please see errors there .. any suggestion ?

Comment: @Katoch Make sure to do a "clean" step before building. Also make sure you don't have any library paths hardcoded in your project file.

Comment: Only thing we have to include is -- CONFIG += qaxcontainer --- then it worked..thanks